# Spring Boot guide authoring: running Sagan with my guide

Tags: spring-boot

To render my own spring boot starter guide, I followed these 2 pages:

- https://github.com/spring-guides/getting-started-guides/wiki/Testing-edits-to-your-guide-and-macros
- https://github.com/spring-guides/getting-started-guides/wiki/Run-sagan-to-test-your-own-content

I can run Sagan, but not with my own guide. Particularly, first wiki page says:

```
Example 1. sagan-site/src/main/resources/application.yml

...
  guides:
    owner:
      name: ${GITHUB_GUIDES_OWNER_NAME:/*your githubusername*/}
      type: ${GITHUB_GUIDES_OWNER_TYPE:users}
...
```

But nowhere in sagan's code it uses `GITHUB_GUIDES_OWNER_NAME`.
I did find `sagan/sagan-renderer/src/main/resources/application.yml`, which defines the organization property, but editing like this didn't get sagan to render [my guide](https://github.com/ge0ffrey/gs-constraint-solving-ai-optaplanner/):

```
sagan:
  renderer:
    guides:
      organization: ge0ffrey
    # github:
      ...
      # token: ${GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN:}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got sagan to render my guide by hacking the sagan code (see below). Basically, **get the guides list from spring-guides, but get your guide from your repository** (`ge0ffrey` in my case).

For what it's worth (not much), here's the patch diff of my local hack:

```
Index: sagan-renderer/src/main/java/sagan/renderer/guides/GuideRenderer.java
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- sagan-renderer/src/main/java/sagan/renderer/guides/GuideRenderer.java   (revision 68d9ced83d8ee97c7972a0d603a9077299c0435f)
+++ sagan-renderer/src/main/java/sagan/renderer/guides/GuideRenderer.java   (date 1578485243882)
@@ -41,7 +41,7 @@
        GuideContentResource guideContent = new GuideContentResource();
        guideContent.setName(guideName);
        String repositoryName = type.getPrefix() + guideName;
-       String org = this.properties.getGuides().getOrganization();
+       String org = "ge0ffrey";
        String tempFilePrefix = org + "-" + repositoryName;

        File unzippedRoot = null;
Index: sagan-renderer/src/main/java/sagan/renderer/guides/GuidesController.java
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- sagan-renderer/src/main/java/sagan/renderer/guides/GuidesController.java    (revision 68d9ced83d8ee97c7972a0d603a9077299c0435f)
+++ sagan-renderer/src/main/java/sagan/renderer/guides/GuidesController.java    (date 1578484725643)
@@ -53,6 +53,13 @@
                .toResources(this.githubClient.fetchOrgRepositories(properties.getGuides().getOrganization()))
                .stream().filter(guide -> !guide.getType().equals(GuideType.UNKNOWN))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
+       Repository optaplannerGuide = new Repository(15L, "gs-constraint-solving-ai-optaplanner",
+               "spring-guides/gs-constraint-solving-ai-optaplanner", "OptaPlanner Guide description",
+               "https://github.com/ge0ffrey/gs-constraint-solving-ai-optaplanner/",
+               "git@github.com:ge0ffrey/gs-constraint-solving-ai-optaplanner.git",
+               "https://github.com/ge0ffrey/gs-constraint-solving-ai-optaplanner.git",
+               "git://github.com/ge0ffrey/gs-constraint-solving-ai-optaplanner.git", null);
+       guideResources.add(new GuideResource(optaplannerGuide));
        Resources<GuideResource> resources = new Resources<>(guideResources);

        for (GuideType type : GuideType.values()) {
@@ -70,7 +77,7 @@
        if (GuideType.UNKNOWN.equals(guideType)) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
-       Repository repository = this.githubClient.fetchOrgRepository(properties.getGuides().getOrganization(),
+       Repository repository = this.githubClient.fetchOrgRepository("ge0ffrey",
                guideType.getPrefix() + guide);
        GuideResource guideResource = this.guideAssembler.toResource(repository);
        if (guideResource.getType().equals(GuideType.UNKNOWN)) {
```

Note that just overriding the `organization` in `application.properties` doesn't work, because it needs to get a full listing of all guides first. Maybe it works if you clone other repositories too (no idea which ones).